# Client Authentication or Mutual Authentication with Mongoose Web Server

Tags: c++, ssl, https, authentication, mongoose-web-server

Ok it is easy to setup **mongoose web server** with **ssl** support if mongoose is authenticating the clients, and it is possible to make https requests with mongoose web server. But can mongoose support "**client**" authentication(possibly with an ssl certificate)  when it is sending out https requests?

If yes then how, if no which alternative library do you suggest?

PS: of course **c/c++** and **windows**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since July 2014 Mongoose DOES support client side certificates.

Answer (score 1):

Mongoose does not support client side certificates.
Your best call is to use digest authentication, which is built in mongoose, or resort to other methods like cookie-based authentication, or oauth, etc.
You can find an example of cookie-based auth in https://github.com/cesanta/mongoose/blob/master/examples/chat.c